# How to code the delegate pattern in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to pass JSON to `VenueIDController` by implementing delegate/protocols. however it doesn't seem to work. Please let me know what I'm missing.
I even put in an log in the fetch method to see if it is getting called but it doesn't even log which means it isn't getting called please help.

I have a `FetchVenuesViewController.h`

```
#import "VenueTableViewController.h" 
#import "VenueIDController.h"

@interface FetchVenuesViewController : UIViewController< VenueTableViewControllerDelegate, VenueIDControllerDelegate>{
    NSDictionary* venueJSON;
    NSDictionary* idJSON;

};

@property (strong) NSDictionary* idJSON;


- (void)VenueFetch;

- (void)IDFetch;


@end
```

In `FetchVenuesViewController.m`

```
@synthesize idJSON;

- (void)IDFetch {

    //request some webservice 


    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
    //save the response



    if (data) {

        id IDJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (!IDJSON) {
           //handle error

        }
        else {


        //do something

        }



    } else {
        // fetch failed

    }

    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
}

-(NSDictionary *)getID{
    [self IDfetch];
    NSLog(@"json%@",idJSON);
    return idJSON;
}
```

In `VenueIDController.h`

```
@protocol VenueIDControllerDelegate;

@interface VenueIDController : UIViewController{

}


@property (assign) id <VenueIDControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(IBAction)getIDData:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol VenueIDControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(NSDictionary *)getID;
@end
```

and in `VenueIDController.m`

```
@interface VenueIDController (){
    NSMutableArray* IDData;
    UIImage* IDBarcode;
}
-(void) displayIDData:(NSDictionary*)data;
@end

@implementation VenueIDController
@synthesize delegate;


-(void) displayIDData:(NSDictionary*)data{

    [delegate getID];


    NSDictionary* idJSON = data;


}
```

Comment: A) are you getting an error? B) please show the implementation of fetchID

Comment: A) I don't get an error B) Will do but seems like getID doesn't get called at all

Comment: added implementation of IDfetch

Answer (score 2):

This seems wrong:

```
-(void) displayIDData:(NSDictionary*)data{

    [delegate getID];


    NSDictionary* idJSON = data;


}
```

You are calling the delegate method and throwing away its result.

Comment: What should I do instead? When I call the delegate method shouldn't it show up in the log as I had included a `NSLog`? But it doesn't show...

Comment: Are you actually setting the pointer to the delegate? It could be that you haven't done so, in which case you are sending a message to `nil`, so nothing is being done.

Comment: as you see above, I am setting the pointer... is it set incorrectly?

Comment: I can't see where you are setting a valid delegate object to the delegate property.

Comment: you are right. trying to log the delegate i get null... how do i set it correctly?

Comment: `delegate` is just a property. So when you create an instance of `VenueIDController` you set the delegate property to be an instance of `FetchVenuesViewController`. It's the same as setting any another property of an object.

Comment: I'm not sure what bit you are having trouble with, but here's an old example https://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip. Have a look at the `editAction` method in `FirstViewController.h` which shows how to create an object and set it's delegate programatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18357/discussion-between-ellieinphilly-and-abizern)